# How to Run Sql Server Update Statement with MVC

Tags: php, sql-server, model-view-controller, yii

I want to update some values in my database table using Update statement using PHP with Sql Server 2008 R2. Can anyone help me to do that ?

Here is the code for that view class. It has only one Button. On Button Click I want to update value of settings

```
    <div class="box span12">
    <div class="box-header well">
    <h2><i class="icon-retweet"></i> Reset State</h2></div>
    <div class="box-content">

 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
     'id'=>'systereset-form',
     'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
     'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'form-horizontal'),
     )); ?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please select State to reset</legend>
    <div class="form-actions">
    <?php echo CHtml::htmlButton('Reset State',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>'submit','name'=>'systemreset')); ?>
</div>
<div class="row buttons">

</div>
</fieldset>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

Here is Controller Class for this View Page

```
public function actionSystemReset(){
    if(isset($_POST['systemreset'])){
        $upd="update settings set value=0 where name='SYS_STATE_VALUE'";
        $update=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($upd)->execute();
        if($update>0){
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('reset','Dear user Kiosk "'.$_POST['systemreset'].'" has been reset successfully.');
        }
    }       
    $this->render('systemreset',array('result'=>$result));
}
```

Comment: where do you assign the "systemreset" value  .. this info is not in your code ... . sjow all your widget code ..

Comment: @scaisEdge. What should i assign to systemreset ?
I am new in MVC

Comment: Update your question  adding l the  view 'systemreset'  code ...

Comment: @scaisEdge, Details added

Comment: Seem missing beginwidget code and the code that precede eventually beginwidget ...

Comment: I have posted an  answer  hope is useful

Comment: @scaisEdge It's working fine. But even i am refreshing or opening page. It's updating value to 0

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only a button and you don't have any name for this button so you can simply (avoid the check for $_POST['systemreset'])

```
public function actionSystemReset(){

    $upd="update settings set value=0 where name='SYS_STATE_VALUE'";
    $update = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($upd)->execute();
    if($update>0){
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('reset','Dear user Kiosk "'.$_POST['systemreset'].'" has been reset successfully.');

    }       
    $this->render('systemreset',array('result'=>$result));
}
```

Comment: Since `$_POST['systemreset']` is not set anywhere, it should not be used in the message sent to the user.

Comment: @moni_dragu, so how i can make it work to show message to user?

Comment: @scaisEdge, It's working fine. But even i am refreshing or opening page. It's updating value to 0

Comment: @JaaZaib, yes the update works, but the rest should not work correct like it is now. You should name your button and check for the posted value.

Comment: @moni_dragu, Name Added. Now how to set it to update only on Button Click

Comment: @JaaZaib it should work with your original code: `if(isset($_POST['systemreset'])){` ...